# Jquery slideshow not hiding images correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, slideshow

I have an image slideshow within an HTML5 flipbook design. When I use the code on a blank webpage, it works fine. But within the flipbook, the last image in the slideshow (sometimes it is a different image than the last) still shows underneath the active image instead of being hidden.

Each image will appear for just a second and then the last image shows up each time. Once the slideshow loops through every image, it works fine.

Any ideas about why this is happening?

Here is my HTML for the book:

```
<div id="outside-content">
<div id="zoom-viewport">
<div id="flipbook">
<div class="hard" style="background-image:url(image.png)"></div>

<div class="hard" id="slideshow" style="margin:0px">
<div><img src="image.jpg"></div>
<div><img src here</div>
<div><img src here</div>
..... many more divs with images....
</div><!-- slideshow end-->

<div>Page</div><!-- title page -->
<div>Page</div>
... more pages ...
</div><!-- flipbook-->
</div><!--zoom-viewport-->
</div><!-- outside-content-->

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#flipbook").turn({
    width: 950,
    height: 615,
    autoCenter: true
});
</script>
```

And here is the Jquery for the slideshow:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
$('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut(2000)
.next()
.fadeIn(2000)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

And the CSS:

```
#slideshow { 
margin: 30px 10px; 
position: relative; 
width: 470px; 
height: 595px; 
padding: 0px; 
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#slideshow > div { 
position: absolute; 
top: 0px; 
left: 0px; 
right: 0px; 
bottom: 0px;
}
```

I have tried changing the number in gt(0) to -1 or 1 and have tried removing the '>' but nothing changes.

Comment: have you hidden all  the divs then starting fresh `$("#slideshow div").hide();`

Comment: That worked @Billy! I added it after the <script> tag before '$("#flipbook").turn({' and works perfectly now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it worked laustewa14. I'lln put it as an answer so you can mark the question as answered. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hide all the divs then start fresh

```
 $("#slideshow div").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using another way? If not please try this.

```
<div id = "slider">
<ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide"><img src = "resources/banner1.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src = "resources/banner2.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src = "resources/banner3.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The JQuery code:

```
$(function() {
var width = 693;
var animationSpeed = 500;
var pause = 3000;
var $slider = $('#slider');
var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
var interval;
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
var clickcount = 0;
$("#icon").addClass("pauseicon");

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');


function startSlider() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        nextSlide();}, pause);
}

function nextSlide() {
    $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
    $('#slider ul').css('margin-left', 0);
    var value = parseInt($(".pager").text(), 10) + 1;
    if(value === 4){ value = 1;}
    $(".pager").text(value + "/3");
    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-693px'}, animationSpeed);

}

startSlider();});
```

The CSS:

```
#slider {
      width: 693px;
      height: 434px;
      overflow: hidden; }
 #slider .slides {
        display: block;
        width: 2079px;
        height: 434px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0; }
    #slider .slide {
        float: left;
        list-style-type: none;
        width: 693px;
        height: 434px; }
```

Include the script via your normal call of a javascript. `<script type = "text/javascript" src = "slider.js"></script>`, put the script call before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: You could have changed it a bit from Flexslider to the OP's classes etc to try and help him along rather than copy /paste

Comment: It's hard to understand the problem above because there is no live demo. If there is I could have helped him/her rather than the copy paste. Sorry.

Comment: @LykaSanPedroHementera thank you for this but I'm having trouble implementing it. Should it be enclosed in something with the 'slider' ID to grab that?

Comment: Thank you! I actually got the first comment to work but I'll save this one for future reference :)

Answer (score 0):

Had problems with this as well until I wrapped the `slideshow` javascript in a function.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function() { 
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(2000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
     },  3000);
});
```

Then it worked perfectly!